# Can't edit some questions on Stack Overflow на русском and Русский язык

Tags: bug, edits, 404-not-found, russian-stackoverflow, russian-stackexchange

For some reason, trying to edit [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/120086/223536) results in a 404. This could be related to the fact that there is no Post History for this question. See [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/967948) which returns no results; also, the API isn't able to fill the `body_markdown` field.

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/967949/posts-without-history) lists 13 posts on Stack Overflow на русском for which this problem occurs.

I've [networkwidified the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/967955/questions-and-answers-without-history-networkwide); it produces some false positives were the post was deleted while the last SEDE refresh took place. The other hits around the network are [half a dozen Русский язык posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/rus/query/967949/posts-without-history) and [this answer on Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/12781/19591).

Comment: One does not simply to edit questions on SOru (¬‿¬ )

Comment: In Soviet Russia, questions edit you ... Any idea if it was already reported there? I suspect it has something to do with the hashcode.ru migration.

Comment: Not sure if it has been reported already. But yeh, I guess it is related to migration. Just strange to see questions from 2014 in this query result.

Comment: [Reported almost year ago on ruSO meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6912/176217)