# Where can I ask if a bug affects multiple sites?

Tags: support, mathjax, bug-reports

The [[bug] tag excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/63170/8) read(s):

> Use this tag for a reproducible problem ON THIS SITE

I have a MathJax problem, reproduced at [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour), [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), and [MathOverflow.SE](https://mathoverflow.net/tour). [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) doesn't use MathJax. Where should I report (make a post about) it? Would Meta.SE work?

Comment: I was going to complain that it actually says “ON A STACK EXCHANGE SITE” rather than “ON THIS SITE”, but now I see that this clarification of the tag excerpt was done only a few minutes ago. Thank you, @Glorfindel.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you're welcome. I was in the process of writing an answer, but that took a bit longer and Meta regulars are fast :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard [tag excerpt for [bug]](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info) reads as follows:

> Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed.

The one used here is a bit older, and [has been enriched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/63170/revisions) to discourage users from posting questions about bugs in their own software development projects here. (Not sure how effective that is, but it doesn't hurt.)

I understand where your confusion comes from, so I edited it into

> PROGRAMMING AND DEBUGGING QUESTIONS DO NOT BELONG ON META. Use this tag for a reproducible problem ON A STACK EXCHANGE SITE that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.

(improvements are welcome, y'all can suggest edits and some veterans can edit tag excerpts directly)

Even if a bug only occurs in a single site (because it's about [site-specific formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/295232), or it relates to the site's history, similar to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322543/295232)), it's still OK to post it here if it's related to the Stack Exchange *system/software*.

Posting it on a site's own meta is also fine, but staff usually won't see it unless it gets a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag; here, Community Managers may notice it even without that tag. Or regulars may find related/duplicate questions and provide you with more information. One of the downsides of posting on Meta.SE: the problem may be hard/impossible to reproduce if the site-specific formatting isn't enabled here. But screenshots will go a long way.

Answer (score 8):

If the bug is specific to a site, use the site's meta.

If you've found the bug on multiple sites, post it on Meta.SE. Even though Meta.SE does not use MathJax itself, bugs that are apparent on multiple sites go here.

There are currently 239 [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax) questions on this site.